# Can you display RSS feed with SimplePie on the blog it was pulled from?

Tags: wordpress, rss, simplepie

I want to fetch an RSS feed that my Wordpress site creates (let's call it `site1.com/feed`) using Simplepie, and I want to display that feed on the homepage of the same Wordpress site (`site1.com`). But I can't get the feed to display at all.

I've pulled the feed and put it on a different website (`site2.com`), which worked. However, when I try to display the WP feed (`site1.com/feed`) on the site it's generated from (`site1.com`), I get nothing.

Sorry if the explanation is a bit convoluted. It's hard to get it out in a succinct way. But anyway, is this an issue with Simplepie itself? Can you just not display a feed on the site that generates it?

Answer (score 0):

Why use simplepie? Just use the standard Worpdress code to output your feed within your site.